# Prove $G$ group $A,B<G$ has surjective function from gA to b(A$\cap$B).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, analysis

Prove that if G is a group and $A,B<G$, then there is a surjection function from the side classes from $A$ to $G$ into the side classes A$\cap$ B to B.

My attempt:

Let $g \in G$ not equal $0$ we have that $gA=[ga: \forall a \in A]$.

We note that the number of elements in gA remains the same as in A because it does not have zero divisors.

$|A|=|gA|$.

In a similar way it will be evaluated for b(A$\cap$B).

|A$\cap$B|=|bA$\cap$B|.

By the properties involving intersection:

|A|>=|A$\cap$B|

Case (1) A=B

So gA$\cap$gA = gA , therefore |gA|=|gA| there is a one-to-one function between them which is in turn one-to-one.

Case(2)A $\not\equiv$ B.

|A|>|A$\cap$B| =>

|gA|>|b(A$\cap$B|

So  |gA|>|b(A$\cap$B| , then by the cardinality properties we will have that there is a surjective function from gA to b(A$\cap$B).

My doubts are:

Is the proof correct?

Is there a better way to resolve this issue?

I would like if possible someone tell me which property or a more formal explanation of why |A|>|A$\cap$B| I can believe and understand but I can't formalize why this is valid.

Comment: The proof is wrong. First of all you seem to assume that $G$ is finite. Second, you have **not** defined a map which is supposed to be onto. Then if $A=B$, the number of left cosets of $A\cap B$ in $B$ is just $1$. Then you defined $g$ as an arbitrary element of $G$. But you have not defined $b$.  The negation of $A=B$ is **not** $A\not\equiv B$.  And so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show that $[G:A]\ge [B:A\cap B]$. For this it is enough to find an *injective* map from the set of left cosets $\{b(A\cap B)\| b\in B\}$ to the set of left cosets $\{gA\|g\in G\}$. Then there is a *surjective* map in the opposite direction:  from the set of left cosets  $\{gA\|g\in G\}$, to the set of left cosets $\{b(A\cap B) \| b\in B\}$  (if there is an injective map from a set $X$ to a set $Y$, then there is a surjective map from $Y$ to $X$).

The map is $f: b(A\cap B)\to bA$.

1. This map $f$ is well defined (so it is a map). Indeed if $b_1(A\cap B)=b_2(A\cap B)$ then $b_1^{-1}b_2\in A\cap B$, so $b_1^{-1}b_2\in A$, hence $f(b_1(A\cap B))=b_1A=b_2A=f(b_2(A\cap B))$.
2. This map is injective. Indeed, suppose $f(b_1(A\cap B))=f(b_2(A\cap B))$, that is $b_1A=b_2A$ where $b_1,b_2\in B$. Then $b_1^{-1}b_2\in A\cap B$, so $b_1(A\cap B)=b_2(A\cap B)$.